# mgp25 instagram API Upload Story and Mention a user within it

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the mgp25 Instagram API and have the following question,
I want to tag/mention a user within a story. I can easily now make hashtags or add a link to a story with this API, but from the examples and source code I cannot get the concrete code about tagging/mentioning a user in a story like a sticker:

Picture of user mentioning / tagging via Instagram story

[image: picture of user mentioning / tagging via Instagram story]

I opened already an issue at the GitHub:
https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/issues/1826

This is the code I created from existing source code from the API and from examples, but there is no concrete example for this use case, and it doesn't work:

```
'story_mentions' =>
[
        'user_id'          => '123456789',
        'x'                => 0.5,
            'y'                => 0.5,
            'width'            => 0.5661107,
            'height'           => 0.10647108,
            'rotation'         => 0.0,
            'is_sticker'       => true, // Don't change this value.
],
```

Maybe someone has an Idea or implemented it already, furthermore, the example of the location sticker doesn't work as well :/

Thanks and kind regards!